# having trouble in getting value of input box that have user defined index in jquery

Tags: jquery, inputbox

```
<input id="start[2]" type="input" value="10" name="start[2]">
```

I know the index 2 and I am getting value of this input box using jquery, like this:

```
str="#start[2]";
result = $(str).val();
alert(result);
```

but it alerts `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From jQuery **[docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\

So you need to do:

```
str="#start\\[2\\]";
result = $(str).val();
alert(result);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z66ms/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `[` and `]` using `\`

but `\` is also special character so you have to escape it also `\\`

```
result = $("#start\\[2\\]").val();
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/PBdsN/)</kbd>

Comment: Can I use your answer in my answer ?

Comment: @AmitJoki if you have Better answer than yes but if it's same there is no use of duplicate answer .

Comment: Just wanted to give a demo. So I asked. But you edited your answer with a fiddle.

Comment: @AmitJoki `<kbd>Button</kbd>` like this :)

Answer (score 0):

you can refer the given fiddle link for this

```
 <input id="start[2]" type="input" value="10" name="start[2]">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GA63Y/